# ":bufdo cd ~/Some/Folder/Path" doesn't affect all files

Tags: buffers

I have about 15 files in my buffer list [1].  In my one and only tab, I have three modifiable subwindows, none of which have unsaved changes.  I issue `:bufdo cd ~/Some/Folder/Path`, and Vim lists each buffer processed.  No error messages are shown.

I then issue `:windo pwd`, and two of the three subwindows show paths other than ~/Some/Folder/Path.  **What steps can I use to track down the reason?**

Note that `:windo cd ~/Some/Folder/Path` succeeds in changing the *pwd* of all subwindows in a tab, but I often have multiple tabs open.  With some occassional exceptions, I often want to maintain a single global *pwd*.

**NOTES**

[1]  As seen by BufExplorer.  Note that this is not a BufExplorer question.  I simply use BufExplorer as a nice way to view buffers.

Comment: `:cd somedir` changes the working directory to `somedir` globally so I wonder why, exactly, you would want to do it n times in a row instead of once. Did you check `:help :lcd` and `:help :tcd`?

Comment: Do you have some plugin that set the working directory (e.g. [Startify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-startify), [Vim-Rooter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter))?

Comment: @Vivan De Smedt: Not that I'm aware of.  The problem with disparate pwd's is sporadic.  Sometimes, `cd` sets the pwd for all buffers/tabs/windows.  Sometimes not.  Over the years, if not decades, I haven't figure out what causes some files to be immune to `cd`.  I'm unable to make it happen at will, making very hard to investigate the conditions that lead the problem.

Comment: Since Vim does have the notion of pwd's that are specific to the subwindow and tab, I was wondering if there is documentation on these non-global pwd's beyond the help. For example, do they always exist as separate data, but forced to mirror the global pwd, or are they simply pointers to the global pwd until commands such as `lcd` or `tcd` force the creation of separate data? At what point do they become pointers again, or if they are separate data, at what point are they forced to mirror the global pwd again? Insight into such bookkeeping could inform where to look for the problem.